# Как передать ссылку на курсор в переменную, а затем использовать его? Как избежать повторения? Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть примерно такой код:

```
PROCEDURE PROC (CONDITION VARCHAR2)
   CURSOR C1
     IS
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
   CURSOR C2
     IS
      SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
   CURSOR C3
     IS
      SELECT * FROM TABLE3;
BEGIN
   IF CONDITION = '1' THEN
      FOR LINE IN C1 LOOP
          *(одинаковый код)*
   ELSIF CONDITION = '2' THEN
      FOR LINE IN C2 LOOP
          *(одинаковый код)*
   ELSE
      FOR LINE IN C3 LOOP
          *(одинаковый код)*
END;
```

Вопрос: как можно избежать повторения в блоке BEGIN/END? Ведь различается только курсор, всё остальное (в том числе столбцы во всех курсорах) одинаковые. Очень хочется каким-то образом записать "ссылку" на курсор по условию в переменную, чтобы потом вызвать цикл с нею и избежать беспощадного повторения кода.

Через `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` сделать не могу, так как в цикле перезаписываются переменные, выполняется другой `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` (хотя, возможно, есть "промежуточный" вариант, чтобы не засовывать весь цикл в EXECUTE?). Знаю, что есть конструкция REF CURSOR, однако, как я понял, это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Возможно, ошибаюсь.

UPD: примерный код внутри цикла:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT INTO VARIABLE1 --> Выполняется SELECT из переменной в другую переменную    
  IF (VARIABLE2) THEN --> Сверка по заданной вне цикла переменной        
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE USING LINE.Q --> Переменная из цикла и курсора    
  END IF; 
INSERT INTO LOGGING_TABLE (col1, col2, col3, col4) SELECT (var1, var2, var3, LINE.Q) --> Записывается в таблицу логгирования несколько переменных вне цикла, а также переменная в цикле
```

Comment: Приведите кусок этого *(одинакового кода)*, что бы было понятно, почему нельзя динамический sql использовать ну и в целом было понятно, что вы там делаете. Пока вижу 2 варинта: динамический курсор, процедура, с передачей курсора.

Comment: @SwaD к сожалению, по некоторым причинам, не могу написать код полностью. Цикл FOR выглядит примерно так:
`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT INTO VARIABLE1 --> Выполняется SELECT из переменной в другую переменную
   IF (VARIABLE2) THEN --> Сверка по заданной вне цикла переменной
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE USING LINE.Q --> Переменная из цикла и курсора
   END IF;
INSERT INTO LOGGING_TABLE (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT (var1, var2, var3, LINE.Q) --> Записывается в таблицу логгирования несколько переменных вне цикла, а также переменная в цикле`
Надеюсь, хотя бы общее представление сложится...

Comment: Все не надо, основные моменты нужны. И код в вопрос добавьте. Из того, что я вижу, нет каких то запретов на использование динамического запроса.

Comment: @SwaD вероятно, вы правы. Беспокоюсь, что код в переменной (полагаю, тип переменной будет varchar2) для `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` будет тяжело поддерживать и плохо читаем. Поэтому надеялся, что есть какой-то способ записать "ссылку" в переменную или присвоить курсору новую переменную и просто вызывать новую переменную.

Comment: Исходя из описания ясно, что *(одинаковый код)* - это код, который можно вынести в процедуру вида procedure some(p_in_1 in …). Это самое простое решение. Решение посложнее с ссылкой на курсор, так же можно реализовать. Создать процедуру, которая открывает курсор в зависимости от параметра procedure open_cur(p_ref out sys_refcursor, p_what in pls_integer). Вызывать открытие курсора и в цикле работать.